# Will this code run in UI thread?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

For example, My UI thread execute a SwingWorker thread, called as A. In the done() function of A thread, it create a SwingWorker thread B. Now, the code in the done() function of thread B is running on UI thread or thread A?

It make sense that, the code should be running on thread A, but if I don't call get() function in thread A, thread A will not wait for thread B and thread A probably will finish its task. If thread B now execute the code in done() function, thread A is not there already. Then how the code be handled in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [SwingWorker API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) documentation, `SwingWorker#done()` runs on the Swing event dispatch thread (EDT). This is true for both `done()` methods that you mention above. You know that there's an easy way to find out by using the `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` method.